# Use generic class for generic parameter base with out generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is it possible to do some thing like this in C#?

```cs
class Foo<T> where T : Bar{}
class MyClass<TFoo> where TFoo : Foo<> {}
```

I don't want to use it like this. in real thing it get 5+ generic parameter

```cs
class Foo<T> where T : Bar{}
class MyClass<TFoo, T> where TFoo : Foo<T> {}
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible. Often a workaround is to introduce a non-generic base class (`Foo` in this case).

Comment: `I don't want to use it like this` - yet, that's the way.

Comment: You can also use you generic as the base class and use ‘object’ as the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), we can see that the languages specification states:

`where T: <base class name>`

> The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class. In a nullable context in C# 8.0 and later, T must be a non-nullable reference type derived from the specified base class.

**Example:**

```cs
public class Foo<T> where T: Bar
{
}
```

and

`where T : U`

> The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U. In a nullable context, if U is a non-nullable reference type, T must be non-nullable reference type. If U is a nullable reference type, T may be either nullable or non-nullable.

**Example:**

```cs
//Type parameter V is used as a type constraint.
public class SampleClass<T, U, V> where T : V { }
```

---

And generally, you can't have a generic declaration syntax like this:

```cs
public class Foo<T> where T: Bar<> // <> using this syntax is not allowed.
```

---

So, the best version for you in the above case could be either:

```cs
class Foo<T> where T: Bar{}
class MyClass<TFoo, T> where TFoo : Foo<T> {}
```

or (as correctly mentioned by @Jon):

```cs
class Foo { }

class Foo<T> where T: Bar { }

class MyClass<TFoo> where TFoo : Foo { }
```